# Does Aunt May ever (permanently) learn that Peter is Spider-Man?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

Seems like Aunt May's ability to be rather astoundingly ignorant of the fact that her nephew is Spider-Man was one of her more endearing traits and she'd be somehow less of an interesting character if she were the Spider-Man's Alfred rather than his constant inspiration.  In the comics, not the MCU, did she ever really (permanently) learn that Peter Parker was Spider-Man?

If she did know his identity for any period of time, how did it change their relationship?

Comment: What is "permanently" in comics?

Comment: I want to write an answer about Civil war and Spiderman coming out to the world, but I don't know how it impacted the relationship, so I am hoping someone else can do it better

Comment: @Andrey not just a dream or a Mephisto induced nightmare (unless said Mephisto induced nightmare lasted more than 12 issues)

Comment: I honestly prefer Sam Raimi's depiction of Aunt May, where she totally knows but never lets on, just giving Peter the right advice at the right time to help him come home safe.

Comment: @PeterTurner: Is there anything more I can add?

Comment: @fuzzyboots, I really want to know how it changes their relationship given what happens in the last 2 seconds of _Homecoming_ (not that that matters since MCU Aunt May is totally different than her comic book counterparts).  I figured in 50 years of Spider-Man that she probably did find out once or twice, so that's the part I'm interested in.

Comment: I have that in my answer for both continuities. In the first, it essentially changes nothing. She accepts him as Peter and as Spider-Man. In the latter, she threw him out, but later accepted him and was proud of him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Courtesy of [her Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aunt_May):

In the main continuity, *The Amazing Spider-Man vol. 2 #35, #38*:

> May finally learned about her nephew's secret life when she walked into his room after he had sustained a serious beating from the villain Morlun, the two later talking about May's discovery as May came to accept her nephew's real life.

The *One More Day* storyline reversed this, much as it did with everything good in the universe.

In the Ultimate continuity, starting with *Ultimate Spider-Man #99*:

> Peter reveals his secret identity to Aunt May after he finds Gwen Stacy's clone at her old house, resulting in May evicting Peter from her home, as she despises Spider-Man. .... She is rescued from dying by Sue Storm of the Fantastic Four, reconciles with Peter and accepts his life as Spider-Man, though she is not at all fond of his costume. Peter later explains to May why he became Spider-Man, and May tells him that Ben would be proud of him for doing so.

This one stuck with [the end of the comic book line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel#The_end_of_the_Ultimate_Marvel) meaning they couldn't "fix" it.

Comment: Are either of these permanent?

Comment: @Edlothiad how would she forget dementia?

Comment: @Edlothiad: The main contuity one was reversed with *One More Day*. That is, if we lived in a cruel universe where something like that would have been published. :)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/34sk0t/how_did_spiderman_regain_his_secret_identity/

Comment: @Edlothiad: What a fascinating bit of AU fiction... :-P

Comment: I believe it's from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Moment_in_Time_%28comics%29