# Is there any precedent for Aunt May being Spider-Man's techie/helper?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse*, the Aunt May in Miles' universe is shown to not only know that Peter Parker is Spider-Man (ie - [not asking about this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163459/does-aunt-may-ever-permanently-learn-that-peter-is-spider-man)), but also that she apparently designs gadgets and possibly other equipment and facilities. (She's the Q to James Bond, Lucius Fox to Batman, etc.)

Is there any precedent in the comics or various other media that this idea is pulled from?

Comment: https://nerdist.com/article/spider-man-into-the-spider-verse-aunt-may-reimagining/

Comment: https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/01/03/spider-man-into-the-spider-verse-aunt-may-inspiration-revealed/ - The art of the movie book suggests that she was 'radically re-imagined'

Comment: When I watched "Into the Spiderverse" I was reminded of the setup Peter had in the 1980s cartoon Spider-Man and his Amazing Friends.  Note that was a computer system given to him by Iron Man and most certainly not his elderly Aunt May.  I assumed a similar story for spiderverse the difference being that aunt May knew about it

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible answers to this, but neither deal with either (a) Earth 616 Spiderman, or (b) the 616 version of May Parker.

1. A version of May Parker (I believe) was the armorer for Spider *Gwen* in the **Ultimate Spiderman** cartoon show.
2. May Parker gave the Ultimates universe Miles Morales Peter Parker's old web shooters, so that he may carry on Peter's legacy.

Other than that, I know of no other instances when May was the "Q" to any version of Spiderman. However, this *may* have been possible in a "What if" story, so if anyone has any knowledge of that, it may help....

Answer (score -2):

No story directly says how much she learned from her relationships however she has had access to very powerful and intelligent people. It is not difficult to imagine the Aunt May from the comic books has tech skills. I would say her association with tech geniuses do give her precedent.

In Miles Morales' universe Peter Parker is dead but [Aunt May is still Peter Parker's aunt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MO9ObYD_v0), so everything she experienced in Parker's universe is relevant. This is a parallel universe, everything is parallel unless they say it's different. The city name "New York" is still "New York," for example. We can say Aunt May's history here is the same as the 616 Aunt may until Peter died.  We notice that the first thing Aunt May gives Miles is the best technology Peter had - his web-shooters.

Given her list of acquaintances, It isn't a real stretch that she would have superior technical skills. May has dated Dr. Otto Octavius ([Dr. Octopus](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Otto_Octavius_(Earth-616))) and at one point they were even engaged, until Spiderman foiled the wedding. She has a hip implant he designed. She has also dated J. Jonah Jameson's father, the Mayor of New York City. While Peter was working with the New Avengers both he and Aunt May lived in Stark Tower. While there, she had a brief romance with Iron Man's butler, [Edwin Jarvis](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Edwin_Jarvis_(Earth-616)). As it turned out, that Jarvis was actually a Skrull changeling. She had also dated Martin Li, who was secretly the crime boss [Mr. Negative](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mister_Negative_(Earth-616)) however she didn't know much about his alternate life.

Comment: that all happened in Mile's universe?

Comment: @NKCampbell - Why would that matter?

Comment: just a clarifying question

Comment: @NKCampbell - The Aunt May of Mile Morales is the same Aunt May of Peter Parker. It is Parker's aunt, and she is the one who gave Miles Peter's web-shooters. My point is, this is not a new Aunt May. Everything from the 616 timeline is precedent

Comment: ... except that this is not the 616 universe. There's a list of differences at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/200428/23243. Also, Doc Ock isn't male here (although that doesn't necessarily mean she and Aunt May might not have bumped uglies...)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - No doubt it is a different universe, and Aunt May even says this when she meets 616 Peter Parker. That doesn't automatically make everything in 616 irrelevant. Obviously the city is still "New York" and Peter Parker was still the original Spiderman, and he had an aunt. Good point about Dr. Octavius, however. That may impact her opportunities to get tech savvy. Or it may not (as you said). Generally good policy with "parallel universes" is to assume everything is the same until it isn't. (that's where the term parallel comes from)